# Read a HttpWebRequest stream just before sending it out

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am making a POST request using the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` class and want to ensure that the request is well-formed just before I send it out.

So, I want to print out the entire request stream before it goes out.

I am looking at things in Fiddler but I am still interested in knowing if there is a way to programmatically read a request stream before it is sent out.

The trouble is that the request stream is not seekable, and it is not readable either. How do I read it?

So, this thing won't work:

```
...
accessTokenRequest.Method = "POST";
var accessTokenRequestStream = accessTokenRequest.GetRequestStream();
accessTokenRequestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

accessTokenRequestStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (var reader = new StreamReader(accessTokenRequestStream))
{
  var requestText = reader.ReadToEnd();

  Debugger.Break();

  Debug.Print(requestText);
}

accessTokenRequestStream.Close();
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You're the one writing to the stream, so you know what it contains...

Comment: Of course. But it helps with debugging if you get 400's/bad formed request status codes from the server. And it helps even more if you are sending a request through SSL and don't want to install certificates in Fiddler in order to decrypt secure web traffic.

Comment: Well, you can just prepare the request body in a MemoryStream and copy it to the request stream. You can then examine the MemoryStream if you need.

Comment: That's a nice idea. May be the closest to the correct answer. It won't show me the headers, though. Of course, unless I copy everything, i.e. even the headers to the memory stream. Please write this as the answer and I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Wait! If this stream is not readable, how would I copy from it?

Comment: As for the headers, they're handled separately; I don't think there is an easy way to get the headers and the body in a single stream.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the stream not being readable... The request stream is not, but the MemoryStream is.

Comment: I thought you were suggesting the other way around, i.e. copying the request stream to a memory stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request stream is write-only, there is no way to read it.

What you can do, however, is prepare the request body in a `MemoryStream`, then rewind the `MemoryStream` and copy it to the request stream.